# Windows Server 2008 openssh connection reset

Tags: windows-server-2008, openssh

On Windows Server 2008, I installed openssh but I can't connect it. On Windows Server 2012 it worked.
**The server log:**

```
2708 2020-09-28 14:24:36.368 debug3: checking match for 'Group administrators' user administrator host 42.120.75.144 addr 42.120.75.144 laddr 172.16.12.219 lport 22
2708 2020-09-28 14:24:36.368 debug1: generate_s4u_user_token: LsaLogonUser() failed. User 'administrator' Status: 0xC000000D SubStatus 0.
2708 2020-09-28 14:24:36.368 debug3: get_user_token - unable to generate token for user administrator
2708 2020-09-28 14:24:36.368 debug1: generate_s4u_user_token: LsaLogonUser() failed. User 'administrator' Status: 0xC000000D SubStatus 0.
2708 2020-09-28 14:24:36.368 error: get_user_token - unable to generate token on 2nd attempt for user administrator
2708 2020-09-28 14:24:36.368 fatal: ga_init, unable to resolve user administrator
2708 2020-09-28 14:24:36.368 debug1: do_cleanup
2708 2020-09-28 14:24:36.368 debug1: Killing privsep child 2848
```

**the client log:**

```
Connection reset by 47.116.68.56 port 22
```

Comment: 1) Have you tried dealing with the errors that are apparent in the server log? 2) Doesn't look like you're trying to connect to the same IP address as mentioned in the server log.

Comment: 42.120.75.144 is my client mac ip, I use the command:
ssh administrator@47.116.68.56 
and return:
Connection reset by 47.116.68.56 port 22

Comment: The connection reset suggests that the port isn't opened, are you sure the service is up?

Comment: Perhaps try and specify the domain name while connecting? Is the user named administrator or Administrator?

Comment: @Mogi openssh service is up and 22 port is open, In my 2012 server, it worked

Comment: @JonathanJacobson I also tried two names, but return the same result

Comment: in this thread: https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/2257505-ssh-error-connection-reset-by-peer they point out that 2008 uses older encryption protocols, which after looking at you error log seems as the reason for the connection failure

Comment: @Mogi thanks, maybe It's the right reason, maybe I can have a try and use an old docker image as a client to connect the 2008 server ...

Comment: if you won't find any other solution I would happily post this comment as an answer

Comment: @Mogi ok, I agree this result 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this thread: https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/2257505-ssh-error-connection-reset-by-peer

They point out that Windows Server 2008 uses older encryption protocols, which after looking at you error log seems as the reason for the connection failure.